# Density of $\sin(nx)$

Tags: sequences-and-series, trigonometry

Let $\displaystyle \left(c_n\right)_{n \in \mathbb{N}}$ be the sequence defined by
$$
c_n\left(x\right)=\cos\left(nx\right)
$$ 
and the set $F$ as
$$
F=\underset{n \in \mathbb{N}}{\text{Span}}\left(c_0,c_1, \dots , c_n\right)
$$ 
I've proved that $F$ was dense to the set of $2 \pi $-periodic and continuous functions on $\left[0, \pi\right]$. Can I deduce from it that it is the same if i replace it by $s_n$ with $\displaystyle s_n(x)=\sin\left(nx\right)$  ? (since it is just $\cos(nx+\pi/2)$ )

Comment: I am sorry, when you mention a *sequence of functions* is dense in a set of functions, do you mean: a) *sequence of functions* is a basis (like Fourier), b) *sequence of functions* is a subset?

Comment: To further elaborate on my question, for this $2\pi$ periodic function
$$f(x)=\left\{\begin{matrix}
\frac{x - k\pi}{\pi}, x \in [k\pi,(k+1)\pi)\\ 
\frac{(k+2)\pi - x}{\pi}, x \in [(k+1)\pi,(k+2)\pi)
\end{matrix}\right. $$
how do you prove $\forall \varepsilon >0, \exists n_{\varepsilon}$:
$$|f(x) - \cos{(n_{\varepsilon}x)}|<\varepsilon, \forall x\in [0,\pi]$$

Comment: Arf i made a mistake i edit sorry

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about: $s_n(0)=0$ for all $n$, any function $h$ in
$$
H = \mathrm{span}(s_0,s_1,s_2,\cdots)
$$
satisfies $h(0)=0$.  But the constant $1$ is $2\pi$-periodic, and cannot be approximated uniformly (or even pointwise) by functions in $H$.